# How are the names of memory registers assigned?

Tags: c++, memory

I have programmed quite a bit in Matlab for graduate level numerical analysis courses and for stats simulations, but I am now trying to learn a more general purpose language.  I am teaching myself C++, using Lippman's "C++ Primer".  While working through the section on Pointers, I came across something that confused me.  I compiled and ran the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int ival = 42;
  int *p = &ival;

  std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
```

I intended for this to give me the memory address where ival was held, and it seemed to work.  Here is the output:

```
$ g++ pointer.cpp -o pointer 
$ ./pointer 
0x7fff5fbffa7c
```

This confused me for a couple of reasons.

1)  This is a 12 digit Hex number.  This seems to imply that there are at least 16^12 (=2^48) bits (or bytes) of available storage.  But, I have 4 GB of DDR3 RAM installed, so I should only have 4*2^30 Bytes = 32*2^30 Bits = 2^35 Bits of storage available.  So, my question is:  Is this address actually in RAM, or is it in the Cache of the processor?  If it is in RAM, how are the memory registers labeled in RAM?  Or, am I just completely off the mark?  It doesn't seem possible that there is a memory register corresponding to every 12 digit hex number (or even 11 digit, if the left-most digit is held constant) in my RAM.

2)  Every time I run the program, ival is stored in the exact same place.  This remains true if I rename the variable and change its value.  If create a second variable, kval, it's location is at:

```
0x7fff5fbffa78
```

4 bytes away from ival's location.  (I'm now assuming the address is labelled in bytes because an int uses 4 bytes.)  Does the C++ compiler always start with the same memory address when it builds the program?

I am working on a MacBook Pro, with 4GB of DDR3 RAM and 6 MB of L2 Cache (I know, it's a 5 year old machine), and am using the g++ compiler.  I hope to eventually learn assembly to really understand how these things work, that's why I'm digging a bit deeper into this.

I have tried to find this information on Google and on Stack Overflow, but haven't had any luck.  Also, as far as I can tell, this is not addressed in the C++ book I'm working out of.

Thanks in advance for your time, and please let me know if there is any other info that would be helpful.

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two words - *virtual memory*.  Memory addresses you see being used in code are not physical memory addresses, they are virtual memory addresses that the OS maps to physical memory addresses behind the scenes.  This lets the OS allow different processes to use the same memory addresses internally but keep them physically isolated from each other, mapping each process's pool of virtual memory to different areas of physical memory, or even to HDD space when available RAM is exhausted.

The fact that your output contains more than 8 hex digits means you are likely compiling a 64bit program (which uses addresses with up to 16 hex digits).  If you recompiled the program for 32bit, you would see a different output.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  This was exactly what I was looking for.  I figured there was something else that I wasn't understanding.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

1. Your OS implements [*virtual memory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). Memory is not contiguously allocated, so your pointer really does point to valid memory (from the point of view of your process).
2. The C++ compiler will likely put variables in similar places for similar programs. However, it's not only up to the compiler, the OS can also affect this (eg. with [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I did not know about the extra layer of virtual memory.  I would upvote your answer, but since I'm new, I don't have a high enough reputation yet.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

1. The address is the location of the pointer "p" in the "virtual" memory of the process. Read about "virtual memory management" to understand how the operating system manages the memory. Wikipedia has a very good article on that: [Virtual Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)
2. The address of local variables depends on two things: 1. the compiler, and 2. where the OS loads the text segment of the process. Most compilers will perform some optimization techniques that may result in the variables being moved around. The absolute locations will also change if the operating system implements full ASLR.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I did not know about the extra layer of virtual memory.  I would upvote your answer, but since I'm new, I don't have a high enough reputation yet.  Thanks again!